# xna switching between games

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am currently making a game in XNA, which is basically composed of a series of short mini-games.
Currently, I have two mini-games, represented by their own classes, Game1 and Game2.

Is it possible to switch to the second mini-game once the player finishes the first, and if so, how can it be done, while keeping their score?

Answer (score 0):

Since the "Game" class is the game loop (read input, transform, and render) I don't think it is a good idea to duplicate this class within an XNA project.  Rather, I would create a state engine (a simple enum of the state of the game i.e. MainMenu, MiniGame1, MiniGame2, Paused, etc.) and process each specific minigame in the Game1 class according to a gameState variable. For example

In your Game1.Draw Method

```
switch(gameState)
{
  case: GameState.MiniGame1 
  {
       minigame1.Draw(spriteBatch);
  }break
  case: GameState.MiniGame2 
  {
       minigame2.Draw(spriteBatch);
  }break;
}
```

Your mini games are more like levels that should be loaded into the Game1 class rather than stand alone games.  Of course ,this is a trivial example but hopefully, you get the idea.